# Line in from Nintendo Switch to wireless headphone transmitter buzzes when Switch HMDI makes contact with monitor input

Tags: audio, hdmi

I'm quite bewildered; I can hear Nintendo Switch output cleanly through the wireless transmitter (Steel Series Arctis 7), but as soon as I plug the HMDI from the Switch into the monitor, in fact as soon as it makes any contact, I hear a decently loud constant buzz. The line in for the transmitter is shoddy as it is, but why in the world is the HMDI connection causing this interference?

Note that there is only ever a single HMDI input to the monitor at one time, and that the wireless transmitter is plugged into a PC at all times.

Update: I fixed the buzzing by simply turning up the Switch volume all the way up, but I am still curious what would cause this to happen.

Comment: You probably have a bad earth connection somewhere ....

Comment: To add to the comment above, you could try to use a ground loop isolation adapter to try and fix the buzz (google/Amazon is your friend)